# How to check that the ResultSet returned without a match?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application where I have a login view and I would like to check if the ResultSet returns with no match, to write an alert text under the button. But as I heard ResultSet never returns with null value. So what should I use? Here is my short code:

```
 loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
            final String getUser = "SELECT username FROM userList WHERE username=?";
            try {
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(getUser);
                pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(txtUsername));
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if(rs == null) { //change this line
                    txtAlert.setText("ERROR: No match!");
                    }
                    else {
                        users.add(rs.getString("username"));
                    }
                }
                final String getUserName = users.get(1);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if rs is null your app will crash at the while line. Makes no sense to check for null after calling .next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check what you've added

```
while (rs.next()) {
   users.add(rs.getString("username"));
}

if (users.isEmpty()) {
   // not found!
}
```